# Can't access property due to wrong generic name (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I need to use the old owl carousel which is based on jQuery. Changing a setting during runtime worked like so in the past:

```
$('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').options.nav = false;
$('.owl-carousel').trigger( 'refresh.owl.carousel' );
```

But for $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel') the console outputs undefined as you can see at my codepen. That seems to happen as there is no owl.carousel. Instead there are only two generic **jQuery224029705171181195xxxx** where one of them contains owl.carousel. As the number is generic I can't really access it. Did browsers change the way they name generic properties/objects or did they implement some sort of layer in between?

https://codepen.io/helloworldstudios/pen/mdzwNxZ

Kind regards,
Fabian

Comment: That's nothing with browser, but probably the library changed. The .data() is empty on the .owl-carousel.

Comment: you can try Object.keys ?. `console.log(Object.keys($(".owl-carousel")[0])[0])` gives that. but there has to be a better way

Comment: @EliasSoares thank you, but in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339140/change-owl-carousel-2-options-after-setup Daniel Iser comments that this should work in 2.3.4 which is the latest version. But the comment is from 2020 so I thought that browser might have changed the game.

Comment: @cmgchess that just outputs Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: I just changed the owl version to 2.2.0 and „owl.carousel“ is still a child of a generic „jQuery3640033867461041860562“

Comment: are you sure i did `console.log(Object.keys($(".owl-carousel")[0])[0]);` just where you have console logged in codepen

Comment: @cmgchess, sorry I was using Dev tools and didn't pick the codepeniframe as target. That way it works, but it would be a pretty dirty workaround. But thanks anyways. :-)

Comment: @haeki sorry i have no jquery background

Comment: Just checked it on my old mac which uses Safari 7.0.6 and here everything work's fine. So it seems like newer browsers started to output these generic in between layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Diagnosis

The reason `.data('owl.carousel');` returns `undefined` for you is because the data has not yet been populated from the Owl Carousel library into the element `data` yet.

When the `.owlCarousel()` method is invoked, [this line is fired](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/4eedccac4ea061931162a86e3f268332c16a1ad0/src/js/owl.carousel.js#L1727):

```js
data = new Owl(this, typeof option == 'object' && option);
```

This calls the function constructor, which calls [this method](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/4eedccac4ea061931162a86e3f268332c16a1ad0/src/js/owl.carousel.js#L174):

```js
this.initialize();
```

Which then [triggers the `initialized` event](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/4eedccac4ea061931162a86e3f268332c16a1ad0/src/js/owl.carousel.js#LL529C3-L529C31):

```js
this.trigger('initialized');
```

Then, your custom `onInitialized` callback is called.

However, only after your `onInitialized` callback has been called is when the `.data()` is populated in [`$.fn.owlCarousel()`](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/4eedccac4ea061931162a86e3f268332c16a1ad0/src/js/owl.carousel.js#L1728):

```js
$this.data('owl.carousel', data);
```

## Solution

Try accessing the `.data()` after the `.owlCarousel()` method call in a separate expression afterwards, so that the `.data()` has been populated from the `.owlCarousel()` call:

```js
console.clear();
var owl = "test";
$(document).ready(function () {
  owl = $(".owl-carousel");
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    margin: 10,
    speed: 400,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    slideTransition: "linear",
  });
  console.log($('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel'));
});
```

```css
.item{
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
}

body{
  height:4000px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-default">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could use `this` to get the current `Owl` object that the `initialized` event is for:

```js
console.clear();
var owl = "test";
$(document).ready(function () {
  owl = $(".owl-carousel");
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    margin: 10,
    speed: 400,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    slideTransition: "linear",
    onInitialized() {
      console.log(this);
    },
  });
});
```

```css
.item{
  height:200px;
  background-color: red;
}

body{
  height:4000px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-default">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, thank you. So basically the callbacks like „onInitialized“ are not so usable by design?

Comment: They are usable.